# Macro not working on cells with more than one character

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has 29 columns of headers in row 6. Underneath the 29 headers, there is numerical data that extends to 10000 rows. I want to select a header and then enter a minimum value and a maximum value and any data that exceeds the maximum, or is lower than the minimum for that header column, the row that violates the criteria gets deleted.

I was thinking of a user inputting a minimum and a maximum value in cell A1 and A2 then selecting a header from a drop down box then it runs and removes the rows that violate the boundary conditions. So far I have this.

```
Sub deleterows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Min As Integer
Dim Max As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim HeaderRange As Range
Dim matchval As Double
Dim str As String

'Finding column number for the header
'Header is selected in Row 3, headers for the data is in row 6
matchval = Application.Match(Range("A3"), Range("A6:AC6"), 0)
str = Split(Cells(, matchval).Address, "$")(1)

Set HeaderRange = Range(str & "6:" & str & Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Find(What:=str, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Cells(1, 1).Value <> "" And IsNumeric(Cells(1, 1)) Then
       Min = Cells(1, 1).Value
End If
If Cells(2, 1).Value <> "" And IsNumeric(Cells(2, 1)) Then
       Max = Cells(2, 1).Value
End If
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, HeaderRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row To 7 Step -1
    If Cells(i, HeaderRange.Column).Value > Max Or Cells(i, HeaderRange.Column).Value < Min Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Basically, I'm finding the position of the Header and then finding the address, converting it into a string then using the Column index for that header. Then it finds any cell that violates the minimum and maximum condition and deletes it.

However, when I try running this, I run into errors when I'm trying to use headers that have more than a single character. So if I have a header called "V" it runs fine, however if I have one called "Vradial", I get an error saying "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" for line:

```
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, HeaderRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row To 7 Step -1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to go through all the contortions? You take `Cells(, matchval)`, convert it back into an address (by calling `.Address`), and then try to work backwards to the column number.  Just use call `.Column` and use that instead.

Comment: Beyond the contortions, are your 'header' labels in row 6 simply the alphabetic column identifiers? If so, you are only looking up to column AC so looking for column AE isn't going to return anything.

Comment: The header labels aren't alphabetical identifiers, I just used them as an example. My apologies, I'll edit that in the post. In regards to the contortions, it is finding where the text in cell "A3" is in the header column. And then finding column index where it belongs so it can use column to delete the rows.

Comment: Without looking at any other possible sources for errors, you'd probably benefit from qualifying all the ranges you work on with what sheet they are on.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to find in the line `Set HeaderRange = Range(str & "6:" & str & Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Find(What:=str, lookat:=xlWhole)`? The column header again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for your direct question "Why only single character headers work". I also noticed that you have an unnecessary redundancy in the code (already mentioned/noticed in the comments by the user "eirikdaude")

## "Why only single character headers work"

When using the *Find(What:=str)* in the code below, you are finding a letter only (the alphabetic column identifiers). What you should be finding/searching for, is the value (actual text) of the header that is written in the sheet

```
Set HeaderRange = Range(str & "6:" & str & Cells(6, 
Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Find(What:=str, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

You can write the line as follows: (I tested it and works)

```
Set HeaderRange = Range(str & "6:" & str & Cells(6, 
Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Find(What:=Range("A3"), lookat:=xlWhole)
```

## "Unnecessary Redundancy in the Code"

The above correction while it works, is unnecessary. If I am not mistaken the code line with the issue is used to find the header column. If so, you already find the correct header column index from the code below.

```
matchval = Application.Match(Range("A3"), Range("A6:AC6"), 0)  
'This is only the correct header column index because the match/search range starts from column "A"
```

Hence, you can disregard the line that is giving you trouble and write the code as follows: (And do not forget to set *Application.ScreenUpdating=True* at the end ;D)

```
Sub deleterows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Min As long 'if you expect the min or max to have decimals use Double or Single rather than Long 
Dim Max As long
Dim i As long 'I changed from Integer to Long because 99% of the time Long is better than Integer
Dim matchval As long 'application.match returns a position in an array. Hence Long/Integer are better than Double 

'Finding column number for the header
'Header is selected in Row 3, headers for the data is in row 6
matchval = Application.Match(Range("A3"), Range("A6:AC6"), 0)

If Cells(1, 1).Value <> "" And IsNumeric(Cells(1, 1)) Then
       Min = Cells(1, 1).Value
End If
If Cells(2, 1).Value <> "" And IsNumeric(Cells(2, 1)) Then
       Max = Cells(2, 1).Value
End If
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, matchval).End(xlUp).Row To 7 Step -1
    If Cells(i, matchval).Value > Max Or Cells(i, matchval).Value < Min Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Hope this helps you.